# What's the difference between the two cases of adding parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, performance, informix

I want to know what's the difference between:

```
 DBCmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", IfxType.VarChar);
 DBCmd.Parameters["user_name"].Value = p_u;
```

and

```
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", p_u);
```

What's the best practice here, which one is safer, and does one perform better than the other?

Comment: sorry my bad.. I overlooked it. I will just delete the link..

Comment: DBCmd.Parameters.Add has multiple overloads
 DBCmd.Parameters["user_name"].Value = p_u directly assigns the value to the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example shown, the *primary* difference is that it knows the type to use is explicitly `IfxType.VarChar` - this *might* be important, depending on the exact situation, and whether IFX defaults strings as `Char`, `VarChar`, or `LongVarChar`. I honestly don't know which of those it would select by default.

Being explicit is usually a good idea, but there is no need to re-fetch via the indexer, since the new parameter is returned from `Add`; I would probably suggest:

```
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", IfxType.VarChar).Value = p_u;
```

or maybe:

```
DBCmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", IfxType.VarChar, 20).Value = p_u;
```

where `20` is the *size* of the parameter.

Comment: @just_name "more safe" - yes, is we interpret "explicit" as "safe", which is probably not unreasonable; "more performance" - the indexer lookup is a very small additional (and unnecessary) cost, which can be avoided by the `.Add(...).Value = p_u;` that I illustrated above.

Comment: is the second way do `boxing and  unboxing` so it may be less performance ? or can i use it if i'm not sure of the `datatypes` ?

Comment: @just_name there is absolutely no difference in the boxing/unboxing between the two methods; additionally, I'm guessing that `p_u` is a `string` - strings are ***never*** boxed (they are reference-types).

Comment: thanks a lot , this means i could use them interchangeably without fair of performance or casting problems .

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding Marc's answer, `Parameters.Add` to add a value is deprecated - It was replaced with `AddWithValue`

Comment: Strictly speaking, not quite. `SqlParameterCollection.Add(string,object)` was deprecated - but this *isn't `SqlParameterCollection`*. Actually, I'm more of a `CreateParameter` person, because I mainly code against the abstract connection/command interfaces, which *don't have* either of these. Additionally, the overload I recommended `.Add(name, type)` *isn't* deprecated even on `SqlParameterCollection`.